# Custom equality for intersection

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find the intersection and union between two sequences that have related classes. In order to achieve this I would like to be able to provide a custom equality check to the intersect function. I do not want to override the equals and hashcode function. I would like an intersect function that also takes a function to check for equality.

Is there any clean way to achieve this without writing a custom intersection and union function?

Comment: Show us some you've tried so far. Without any code I can only guess what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is probably not supported by the standard library. It is fairly easy to write your custom intersection/union methods. One other possibility is to wrap your instances like so:

```
class Wrapper[E](val wrapped: E) {
    // Override equals/hashCode here
}
```

You then compute the union/intersection of `Wrapper[E]` and then use `unionOfWrappers.map(_.wrapped)` to get what you wanted. Of course, this will cause many `Wrapper` instances to be created and garbage collected.